# Database design import massive csv files is there a more efficient way?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to let users import huge csv files varied between 200k - 1.5m lines. For this I use `LOAD DATA INFILE` which is the fastest way to import those files. Thing is however that I can't check the user input, I have solved this by using a trigger on a table. My table structure is as following: (narrowed down to make it more readable):

**tbl_debtor:** debtor_id (AI), debtor

**tbl_debtor_tmp:** debtor

**tbl_debtor_err:** error

Now the (before insert) trigger is on `tbl_debtor_tmp` where users can literally import anything. In that trigger I check their user input, if okay I'll do a insert on `tbl_debtor`. If the user input is not okay I write to `tbl_debtor_err`. After the import is done I'll do a `DELETE FROM tbl_debtor_tmp`

My question here is, is there a more efficient way? I have about 20 of those table structures which I think is alot.

Comment: Why don't you import it into a staging table (no trigger), then validate it, then move it to the real table?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I haven't heard of it before. Do you have some material to read?

Comment: by staging table i mean a short-lived table that you create, mimicking your real table. What do you mean "I can't check the user input"?

Comment: I mean usually, with >10k lines in a CSV file, I can check the CSV file through php code (without losing performance). How can I check the user input? Some validations that needs to be done are: is it a specific type (int, decimal etc.) , date format, comma or dot, max/min length of characters, not negative etc. If those validation aren't met the user needs to see that their input isn't valid.

Comment: What Neil was inferring is to break process into 2 stages, load the raw csv in to a table and after that use SQL to validate or clean the data on it's way into the final destination. Of course you could use PHP to iterate through the lines in the CSV, clean the data as it processes and then batch the rows in larger inserts so you can ensure a better performance.

Comment: Such a staging table might have `VARCHAR` where the real table would have `DATETIME` or `INT`.  This you allow you, for example, to deal with mal-formed dates and numbers without losing the original text.

Comment: @RickJames I have that in my tmp table every field is a `varchar`. In the real table they are the types they need to be.

Comment: What kinds of checks do you do?  What do you do if some value is 'bad'?  I'm fishing for whether you _need_ triggers (slower) or can do everything via a staging table and few full-table scans (probably faster).

Comment: @RickJames If a value is bad I put them in the `tbl_debtor_err`. The example I've given above is small. But some checks are `max length`, 'min length', 'does a key exist in a different tbl (FK relations)', `is integer`, `not higher than number 12`, `not negative numbers`, `is date` etc. I have about 20 of those structures all kinds of checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `LOAD DATA ... INTO staging ...;` It has VARCHARs in place of INTs, etc.  It also has some unique `id` (perhaps `auto_increment`) for step 3.
2. Copy "bad" rows to `debtor_err` in one pass:

   `INSERT INTO debtor_err
        SELECT ... 
            WHERE LENGTH(..) > .. 
               OR NOT EXISTS( SELECT * ... )  -- FK check
               OR ... > 12`
3. Copy "good" rows to `debtor` table -- Use JOIN to see which ones are good

   `INSERT INTO debtor
       SELECT ...   -- where nec, convert from VARCHAR
           FROM staging s
           LEFT JOIN debtor_err e
               ON s.id = e.id  -- suitable UNIQUE key
           WHERE e.id IS NULL  -- to get the non-error rows`
4. `DELETE FROM staging;` -- Reset for next time.  (Using `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE` may avoid `id` not working 'right' the second time around.)

Suggestion:  Use MyISAM for `staging`; InnoDB for permanent tables.